# RubyMine (7.0.4) is failing to install cmdparse because it requires Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rubymine

The project is using Ruby 1.9.3 and I can't change that. I'm using sauce and sauce-connect. I think they are bringing in cmdparse (3.0.1).

I only get an error when running bundle install from RubyMine. I can run this command from bash (Mac) with no problem. Now I can't run my tests from RubyMine. any advice?

The complete error...
Gem::InstallError: cmdparse requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing cmdparse (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install cmdparse -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Process finished with exit code 5